# Como ocultar una pagina dependiendo de una variable en Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Necesito esconder una pagina en Inno Setup dependiendo de una de una variable `boolean` en Inno Setup, como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear una condicion con la funcion [`ShouldSkipPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents), en la seccion `[Code]`:

```
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
  begin
    if(PageID = TU_PAGINA.ID) and (TU_VARIABLE = True) then
      begin
        Result := True; //al regresar true se omite la pagina
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: muchas Gracias.